# Automatically set values of slicer dependent on user selection in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, dax

Is it possible to select values of a slicer automatically? I have currently 2 slicers.

In my case, the first contains the following 3 options: car, train and plane. Lets assume I choose **car**.

Then I have 5 choices: bmw, audi, volvo, toyota and vw. I want audi and vw to be selected automatically after pressing the car button.

Is that possible or not?

Comment: Have you found other solution to that? Not based on bookmarks?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for to default a slicer after another slicer has been toggled, that is **not** an option.

However. The work-around is using bookmarks.

Let's assume Car, Animal and Laptop are broad categories, each with subsets inside. All part of the same table

```
| Category | Sub-Set |
----------------------
| Car      | Audi    |
| Car      | BMW     |
| Car      | Honda   |
| Animal   | Cat     |
| Animal   | Dog     |
| Laptop   | Lenovo  |
| Laptop   | DELL    |
| Laptop   | HP      |
```

1. Set a 'Default' Bookmark with a Category and Sub-Set Page level filter of all.
2. Set a bookmark for each Category, and pre-select your slicer ( ex. BmkCar has a page level filter of Car and a slicer selection of Audi ) ( ex. BmkLaptop has a page level filter of Laptop and sliver pre-selection of DELL )
3. Test each bookmark.
4. Create a Button for each Category and link your new bookmarks to each category

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apart from that, would it be possible to select all elements of the second slicer? I mean if I select "car" and then after this filter automatically all car brands in the second slicer get selected?

Comment: Sure, that's a possibility. Technically no section on a slicer is all selected.

Answer (score -1):

Use Chicklet slicer it will solve your Problem.